# FFmpeg extract clip - stream frame rate differs from container frame rate (x264, aac)

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, h.264

**Summary**
H.264 video seems to have a really high frame rate that requires a scaling factor to the applied to the duration of video that I'm trying to extract (900x lower).

**Body**
I'm trying to extract a clip from a movie that I have in MP4 format (created using [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)). After trying mencoder and VLC, I decided to give FFmpeg a shot since it was the least troublesome when it came to copying the codecs. That is, compared to mencoder and VLC, the resulting file was still playable in QuickTime (I know about Perian, etc, I'm just trying to learn how all this works).

Anyway, my command was as follows:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:15:51 -t 00:05:59 -i outofsight.mp4 \ 
-acodec copy -vcodec copy clip.mp4
```

During the copy, The following comes up:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 45000.00 (45000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from outofsight.mp4':
  Duration: 01:57:42.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 830 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 720x384, 25 tbr, 22500 tbn, 45k tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 720x384, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 22500 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: libfaac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame= 2591 fps=2349 q=-1.0 size=    8144kB time=101.60 bitrate= 656.7kbits/s
…
```

Instead of a 5:59 duration clip, I get the entire rest of the movie. So, to test this, I ran the ffmpeg command with `-t 00:00:01`. What I got was exactly a 15:00 minute clip. So I did some black box engineering and decided to scale my `-t` option by calculating what value to enter given that 1 second was interpreted as 900 s. For my desired 359 s clip, I calculated 0.399 s and so my ffmpeg command became:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:15.51 -t 00:00:00.399 -i outofsight.mp4 \ 
-acodec copy -vcodec copy clip.mp4
```

This works, but I have no idea why the duration is scaled by 900. Investigating further, each ffmpeg run has the line:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 45000.00 (45000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
```

45000/25 = 1800. Must be a relation somewhere. Somehow, the obscenely high frame rate is causing issues with the timing. How is that frame rate so high? The best part about this is that the resulting clip.mp4 has the exact same feature (due to the copied video codec), and taking further clips from this needs the same scaling for the `-t` duration option. Therefore, [I've made it available](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/614041/web/clip.mp4) for anyone willing to check this out.

**Appendix**
The preamble for ffmpeg on my system (built using MacPorts ffmpeg port):

```
FFmpeg version 0.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --disable-vhook --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --arch=x86_64
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 0 / 52.20. 0
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    1. 4. 0 /  1. 4. 0
  libswscale     1. 7. 1 /  1. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jan  4 2010 21:51:51, gcc: 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)
```

**EDIT**
Not sure whether it was a bug or not, but it seems to be fixed now in my current version of ffmpeg, at least for this video (version 0.6.1 from MacPorts).

Comment: Re-encoding is not a solution and doing a hours worth of decoding for fives minutes of content is unreasonable and likely would not address the underlying issue. Great initial research btw. You are likely correct in assuming that the fps ffmpeg was detecting is the root of your problem. It sounds like a later version of ffmpeg fixed your issue but I'll make a comment. I would have recommended doing a -c copy to a different container format. This can have a variety of effects but this would have been a good next step to experiment with.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem and my solution was the following:

```
        $ffmpegout = array();           
        //10 is the number of images you want from video
        $fracduration = ($info['duration']/10);
```

exec('ffmpeg -y -i /testmedia/'.$info['filename'].' -vf fps=fps=1/'.$fracduration.' -f image2 /testmedia/images/output%03d.jpg 2>&1', $ffmpegout);
            //print_r($ffmpegout);

This gives me 10 images for all the video no matter the length of video

Answer (score 1):

With ffmpeg, the positioning of the options matters. With your example, it is trying to apply -ss and -t to the input. Use it like this will apply the options to the output instead:

```
ffmpeg -i outofsight.mp4 -ss 01:15:51 -t 00:05:59 -acodec copy -vcodec copy clip.mp4
```

With current ffmpeg, the correct syntax would be:

```
ffmpeg -i outofsight.mp4 -ss 01:15:51 -t 00:05:59 -c copy clip.mp4
```