# Record mjpeg with ffmpeg

Tags: webcam, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I want to record a mjpeg stream via ffmpeg, but as the framerate of the mjpeg is very unreliable the result video is at first to fast and the speed changes.

The source i used to test is: http://c-cam.uchicago.edu/mjpg/video.mjpg

Comment: Have you tried the "-sameq" option from [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/93654/ffmpeg-extract-clip-stream-frame-rate-differs-from-container-frame-rate-x264) or the "-re" option [from this other question](http://superuser.com/questions/317398/how-do-i-control-the-streaming-frame-rate-of-ffmpeg)?  I've no idea if they work, but worth a shot...

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the bit-rate, and the tolerance setting (it's controlled by the -bt switch). it needs to be higher than the bitrate divided by the fps, as in:

tolerante > bitrate / fps

**[This script might be helpful.](http://www.pageofswords.net/press/wp-content/files/fftomp4)**